# WPF window corner radius and shadow

Tags: wpf, ui-design

I want to have a window without buttons, with rounded corners and with shadow.
Like this:
[image: Like this]

So this is my XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Password.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Password"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="294" Width="546" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FFE755DD" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Border Background="#FF22173C" CornerRadius="20, 20, 20, 20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the output:

[image: And this is the output]

The shadow isn't rounded.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur gets cropped because your window doesn't own the space around it.

Set `<Grid Margin="20">` to allow the blur to occur in the area you control.